# Cooking beans in soaking water

Tags: beans

I always drain the water I soaked the beans in overnight and cook them in fresh water. But I've been noticing that the water gets a mild dye of the beans so I was wondering if I'm throwing parts of the baby with the bath water, to be proverbial.

Should beans be cooked in the same water they soaked in?